# Outlook is not showing flash content

Tags: microsoft-outlook, flash

I am sending email to customer with flash logo. It works on gmail and etc, But it won't work in Outlook. What is the issue. Is there any solution for this. Help me out.

Thanks

Comment: flash isn't enabled in Outlook. Why in the world is the logo in flash?

Comment: @sathya: how can we enable it in outlook.

Comment: It's a security feature. Also, as Sathya said, *why*?

Comment: @Karan: Sometime client wants animated flash logo to get more interactive.I used google swify tool, but that generates large size file.any good suggestions are welcome

Comment: Will have to see what workable alternatives are there, if any. You might also want to edit your post to explicitly mention that alternatives to Flash are acceptable as well, provided they result in a manageable file size.